# QT, concurrency programming and passing parameters to function

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency

I have a `QList` and want to process all its elements in parallel. The problem is I need to pass an argument to `my_function`. The code below doesn't allow for this.

```
QList<something> output = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(
    input,
    my_function
);
```

I may use a distinct function for each set of parameters. I may use a global variable too. I may try to rewrite the build in QT function too. However, there should be a better solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the argument you want to pass to the function is independent of the items, you can create a functor that extends `std::unary_function<const something&,void>` whose constructor takes the argument you want to pass to it. Then, use the functor where you would use the function. E.g.,

```
struct MyFunctor : public std::unary_function<const something&,void> {
public:
  myFunctor(int s) { _i = i; }
  void operator()(something& str) {
    something.apply(_i);
  }
private:
  int _i;
};

…

MyFunctor myFunctor(i);
QList<something> output = QtConcurrent::blockingMapped(
    input,
    myFunctor
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What argument do you need to pass to the function? You can't directly do this. What you could do is passing the argument to a different structure with an `operator()` defined from which you can access the argument. That is if you don't want to use a global value.

Take a look at the examples [here](http://www.tolchz.net/?p=37).

Comment: I want to pass an integer number (int).